# What different between "pass by reference" and "return by reference"?

Tags: c++

Please consider the following example below first.

```
#include <string>
class myClass{
    private: 
        std::string  m_name;
    public: 
        std::string getName1(){  
            return m_name;
        }
        std::string& getName2(){  
            return m_name;
        }
        const std::string& getName3(){  
            return m_name;
        }
};

int main(){

}
```

What different `getName1`, `getName2`, `getName3` in terms of return type?
Does it mean that `getName1` will *'COPY'* the value of `m_Name`, whereas the rest will NOT?
Is there any relation between *"pass by reference"* and *"return by reference"?*

Comment: Yes, `getName1` returns a copy of the string, and `getName2` and `getName3` return references to the existing string. Many newbies struggle with the fact that (by default) C++ copies objects. Sounds like you understand the concept but don't quite believe it.

Comment: "Does it mean that getName1 will 'COPY' the value of m_Name, whereas the rest will NOT?" The answer to that question is yes.

Comment: do you know what a reference is?

Comment: As for references, look at them as a kind of alias for an actual thing. Whenever you use the alias (the reference) you use the actual thing. So there's really no different kind of references, it's all just a reference. If you pass it as an argument, return it from a function, or store it in a structure doesn't really matter.

Comment: know what a reference is,  but return by a reference sounds brand-new to me after 2 months learn C++ :D . @463035818_is_not_an_ai

Comment: "return by reference" its not a new concept. Its just what you know about reference and returned from a function

Comment: I have thought : | int func( int& x) ...AND .... | int& func( int& x) are the same :D. is that still true?

Comment: "Passing" applies to arguments, "returning" to return values.

Comment: @molbdnilo meaning, there is 2 stages of copying without & ? I have thought we need & for only parameter to avoid copy :(

Comment: The int& is always alias of some int.

Comment: As an exemplary use case, consider `operator[]` of `std::vector`. It needs to return a reference, since we want to work with a vector element, not with its copy.

Comment: Return by reference is relatively rare, but can be useful. `std::vector<T>`, for instance, has two subscripting `operator[]` functions. One returns `T&`, and the other `const T&`. In practice, however, the overwhelming majority of the functions I write do not return references. There are a few, but not many.

Comment: You ask, `Is there any relation between "pass by reference" and "return by reference"?` Provided that the caller holds onto the original object, pass-by-reference is much safer than return-by-reference. That is because the lifetime of the reference in the called function will always be shorter than the lifetime of the original object in the caller. Returning a reference risks "undefined behavior," because the original object might get destroyed, while the reference to it is still being used.

Comment: On a side note, in the C++ context the more common terminology is "pass *a* reference" and "return *a* reference".

Comment: @tbxfreeware "That is because the lifetime of the reference in the called function will always be shorter than the lifetime of the original object in the caller." that is false. The function might store the reference internally, or it might pass it to something else that holds on to the reference.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: No doubt, you are right. I was trying to keep things a level the OP would understand. I wanted the OP to imagine that a reference to a local variable in the calling routine was passed to a function, was used in the function, and then the function returned. I was hoping to avoid unnecessarily confusing explanations about what might happen if the called function passes the reference to some "global" object that holds onto it beyond the lifetime of the caller. I think the point I was making is still valid, but with the exceptions that you cite.

Comment: @tbxfreeware I think I know what you wanted to say, but what you did say was wrong. Simplifying to an extend that the result is wrong is more confusing that telling the truht: Passing by reference is no safer than returning by reference. When references are involved you must take care of the lifetime of the original object as long as the reference is used

Comment: @tbxfreeware It does not have to be a global object btw. `foo make_foo(bar &b) { return {b};}`. Depending on what `foo` does with the reference the caller must make sure the `bar` is kept alive as long as the returned `foo` is used. This isnt an "exception" as you call it, but just another example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reference is a reference. Whether you return it from a function or its a functions parameter type does not change the fundamentals of what a reference is: An alias for the referenced object.

```
std::string getName1();
```

-> A `std::string` is returned. That string is a copy of the member.

```
std::string& getName2()
```

-> A non constant reference to the member is returned. If a caller modifies this reference they are modifying the member. It is important to understand that `getName2` breaks encapsulation. Having the member private and return a non constant reference can be totally fine its just not encapsulation.

```
const std::string& getName3()
```

-> A constant reference is returned. It is important to understand that the caller can observe modifications made on the member via this reference. The caller can just not modify the member via this reference, but the member can be modified through other means.

---

Of course it depends on how the caller stores what the function returns. This will always make a copy:

```
 std::string x = obj.getName...();
```

---

> Does it mean that getName1 will 'COPY' the value of m_Name, whereas the rest will NOT?

Yes thats what is means.

> Is there any relation between "pass by reference" and "return by reference"?

"pass by reference" got its name long before there were c++ references. You can use a pointer to pass something by reference to a function. The name clash between a c++ reference and the general concept of a reference is unfortunate. In C++ you typically use a reference for pass by reference. "return by reference" is not a official term. Its just about returning a reference from a function.

The relation is that both are about references.

Comment: ! your answer is much more better than an ai. Thank a lot , best wish!

Comment: Returning a reference (in itself) does not *prevent* a caller from copying.   For example, if the caller constructs a string using `getName3()` (e.g.  `std::string x1 = MyClass_instance.getName3();`)  or assigns to a string (e.g. `std::string x2; x2 = MyClass_instance.getName3();`) that the strings (`x1` and `x2`) are *copies*, even though `getName3()` returns a reference.  However, `const std::string &cref = MyClass_instance.getName3()` means `cref` directly accesses the member of `MyClass_instance` (and that reference cannot be used to modify the member).

Comment: @Peter what I wrote "Of course it depends on how the caller stores what the function returns. This will always make a copy:..." and " It is important to understand that the caller can observe modifications made on the member via this reference. The caller can just not modify the member via this reference, but the member can be modified through other means."

Answer (score 4):

"Pass by reference" concerns the arguments passed to a function upon calling it. E.g. `void printInt(int &i);`.

"Return by reference" concerns the value returned by a function upon completion. E.g. `int & getInt()`.

The OP code has no examples of "pass by reference", only "return by reference":

`std::string getName1()` returns a copy of `m_name`. The caller thus gets a "snapshot" of the value of `m_name` at the time the function is called. If `m_name` is changed afterwards, the value of the copy stays the same.

`std::string& getName2()` returns a non-const reference to `m_name`. The caller then gets access to `m_name` itself. If the value of `m_name` is changed, the caller will observe the new value through the reference. Since the reference is non-const, the caller can even change the value of `m_name`. It is very important to be aware that if the `myClass` object holding `m_name`is destroyed, then it becomes undefined behaviour for the caller to access the reference.

`const std::string& getName3()` returns a const reference to `m_name`. This is the same as `getName2()` except that the caller cannot modify the value of `m_name`.

Comment: thank @neisen. it was a great help :)